# Shiny combining inputs

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a data set with three laps (15s/lap) each of which shows the different speed for every second:

```
AA <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(10,12,11,12,12,11,12,13,11,9,9,12,11,10,12,9,8,7,9,8,7,9,9,8,9,7,9,10,10,10,7,6,7,8,8,7,6,6,7,8,7,6,7,8,8),
           c(rep("Lap_1",15),rep("Lap_2",15),rep("Lap_3",15))))
```

I want to compare the three laps together, but for the first one I'd like to use a sliderInput to select only some of the 15 secondes. I'm having some difficulties to add that to my code. Here is what I have for the moment:

```
install.packages("shiny")
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

colnames(AA) <- c("Speed","Lap")
AA$Speed <- as.numeric(as.character(AA$Speed))

ui=shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Title here"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput("lap_choose", 
                           label = "Choose the laps",
                           choices = c("Lap_1","Lap_2","Lap_3")),
        sliderInput("secs_1",
                    "Seconds in L1:",
                    min = 0,
                    max = 15,
                    value = c(3,10),
                    step=1)),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("Comparison"))
    )
  )
)

server=function(input,output){
  #data manipulation
  data_1=reactive({
    return(AA[AA$Lap%in%input$lap_choose,])
  })


  output$Comparison <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=data_1(), aes(Speed, fill = Lap)) + 
      stat_density(aes(y = ..density..), 
                   position = "identity", 
                   color = "black", 
                   alpha = 0.8) +
      xlab("Distribution") +
      ylab("Density") +
      ggtitle("Comparison") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=24, face="bold"))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I should use the `secs_1` at some point to update `data_1`, but didn't find out how yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to organize the data so the plot reacts to input$secs_1.

Comment: @RodrigoDíazLupanow yes, that's all the point of my question =D

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding correctly, you want to filter out some values(based on sec_1 sliderInput) if "lap" variable is "lap_1".

Try using ifelse statement in data_1 function.

```
data_1=reactive({
xc <- AA[AA$Lap%in%input$lap_choose,]
gh <- ifelse(xc$Lap == "Lap_1" & xc$Speed %in% c(input$secs_1[1],input$secs_1[2]), 
 FALSE, TRUE)
return(xc[gh,])
 })
```